# How do i replace a single number (from a set of lines) from a list of numbers?

Tags: python, macros

i am new to programming/macroing,etc and i would like to do this.
Should i use word 2007 or Python or something else? i have only those two things currently.

```
original message is this:
hello how are you ref=13515
ofdifaoididpodvjakjeoijknvkln
ikvnoivwoeij,vn,nviojv
nkavjoiewgkjvlkaior
```

this message has a number which is to be replaced by a number in this list

```
876191
11166524
1117225
1116953
798993
793519
1116737
1116691
1116364
1115635
909014
760195
689981
604787
1116217
1104482
869990
886290
1115893
```

and the message should copypaste itself that number of times as there are numbers in that list.

so my result should be

```
hello how are you ref=876191
ofdifaoididpodvjakjeoijknvkln
ikvnoivwoeij,vn,nviojv
nkavjoiewgkjvlkaior
hello how are you ref=11166524
ofdifaoididpodvjakjeoijknvkln
ikvnoivwoeij,vn,nviojv
nkavjoiewgkjvlkaior
hello how are you ref=1117225
ofdifaoididpodvjakjeoijknvkln
ikvnoivwoeij,vn,nviojv
nkavjoiewgkjvlkaior
and so on
```

pls note that the numbers in the list are 6 or 7 or 8 digit numbers

thank you

Comment: Show your code first otherwise it looks like **please do the required for me**

Comment: i have not tried anything at all. i am very new to all of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple Python script will work:

```
template = """hello how are you ref={}
ofdifaoididpodvjakjeoijknvkln
ikvnoivwoeij,vn,nviojv
nkavjoiewgkjvlkaior
"""

replace = [
    876191, 11166524, 1117225, 1116953, 798993,
    793519, 1116737, 1116691, 1116364, 1115635,
    909014, 760195, 689981, 604787, 1116217,
    1104482, 869990, 886290, 1115893]

print ''.join([template.format(r) for r in replace])
```

Which will display:

```
hello how are you ref=876191
ofdifaoididpodvjakjeoijknvkln
ikvnoivwoeij,vn,nviojv
nkavjoiewgkjvlkaior
hello how are you ref=11166524
ofdifaoididpodvjakjeoijknvkln
ikvnoivwoeij,vn,nviojv
nkavjoiewgkjvlkaior
hello how are you ref=1117225
ofdifaoididpodvjakjeoijknvkln
ikvnoivwoeij,vn,nviojv
nkavjoiewgkjvlkaior
.
.
.
```

and so on.

If you would like to write the output directly to a text file, the following will work:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f_output:
    f_output.write(''.join([template.format(r) for r in replace]))
```

If you would also like to read the numbers from a text file, use the following:

```
with open('numbers.txt', 'r') as f_input, open('output.txt', 'w') as f_output:
    for number in f_input:
        f_output.write(template.format(number.strip()))
```

Comment: excellent! @Martin Evans, Thank you sir, ... now i got a page full of python text in python... now how do i make python save it in a normal notepad text

Comment: I have added a version which will write the output directly to a text file for you.

Comment: what words of mine will convey my gratitude to you, i do not know. thank you for your help. now the thing is that my numbers are in a vertical column. in order for me to write them like that 
replace = [
    876191, 11166524, 1117225, 1116953, 798993,
    1104482, 869990, 886290, 1115893]

i have to copy paste each number individually, how do i do it automatically in python. thanks again